# Share folder with SYSTEM user from another machine

Tags: windows, permissions

I need to be able to copy a file from a Windows server to a shared drive. The copy is started from a task which runs under the local SYSTEM account. Can I add the SYSTEM account to the share on the shared drive? At the moment it fails because it doesn't have access rights.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible if they are in the same domain or at least workgroup.

When adding the rights you have to Change "Object Type" to also include Computers then specify the name of the computer in the domain or workgroup (not LOCAL SYSTEM) and press "Check Name" and you should be able to add it.

If you don't want to add a specific computer but any computer in your domain you can use the group "Domain Computers" (I do not know whether there is an equivalent for a workgroup scenario)